# How to express a column which name contains spaces in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have tried wrapping the column name with brackets `[column name]`, single & double quotes, and backticks, none of them works.

Does Spark SQL support columns whose name contains spaces?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Backticks seem to work just fine:

```scala
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1))).toDF("foo bar", "x")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [foo bar: string, x: int]
scala> df.registerTempTable("df")

scala> sqlContext.sql("""SELECT `foo bar` FROM df""").show
foo bar
a
```

Same as `DataFrame` API:

```scala
scala> df.select($"foo bar").show
foo bar
a
```

So it looks like it is supported, although I doubt it is recommended.

Comment: In case if column is hierarchical, then you can select like """ select parent.`foo bar` ..."""

Comment: Thank you It worked. backticks (`) will do the work.

Comment: 1) What spark version do you use> Looks like old one. 2) With `sc.parallelize` it works, but when I tried `spark.read.schema(schema).parquet("D:\\path")` I got error even when I specify the schema with spaces.

Answer (score 28):

Instead of using Brackets like in T-SQL `[column name]` Use **backticks** to wrap the column name `` `column name` ``. This is when you run SQL. You also use Backticks in spark SQL to wrap the column name but use triple quotes as answered by zero323.