# Pyspark Replicate Row based on column value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to replicate all rows in my DataFrame based on the value of a given column on each row, and than index each new row. Suppose I have:

```python
Column A Column B
T1       3
T2       2
```

I want the result to be:

```python
Column A Column B Index
T1       3        1
T1       3        2
T1       3        3
T2       2        1
T2       2        2
```

I was able to to something similar with fixed values, but not by using the information found on the column. My current working code for fixed values is:

```python
idx = [lit(i) for i in range(1, 10)]
df = df.withColumn('Index', explode(array( idx ) ))
```

I tried to change:

```python
lit(i) for i in range(1, 10)
```

to

```python
lit(i) for i in range(1, df['Column B'])
```

and add it into my array() function:

```python
df = df.withColumn('Index', explode(array( lit(i) for i in range(1, df['Column B']) ) ))
```

but it does not work (TypeError: 'Column' object cannot be interpreted as an integer).

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't [iterate over a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993439/typeerror-column-is-not-iterable-how-to-iterate-over-arraytype) like that. You can always use a `udf`, but I do have a non-udf <strike>hack</strike> solution that should work for you if you're using Spark version 2.1 or higher.

The trick is to take advantage of [`pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) to get the index value. We do this by creating a string by repeating a comma `Column B` times. Then we split this string on the comma, and use `posexplode` to get the index.

```python
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")  # first register the DataFrame as a temp table

query = 'SELECT '\
    '`Column A`,'\
    '`Column B`,'\
    'pos AS Index '\
    'FROM ( '\
        'SELECT DISTINCT '\
        '`Column A`,'\
        '`Column B`,'\
        'posexplode(split(repeat(",", `Column B`), ",")) '\
        'FROM df) AS a '\
    'WHERE a.pos > 0'
newDF = sqlCtx.sql(query).sort("Column A", "Column B", "Index")
newDF.show()
#+--------+--------+-----+
#|Column A|Column B|Index|
#+--------+--------+-----+
#|      T1|       3|    1|
#|      T1|       3|    2|
#|      T1|       3|    3|
#|      T2|       2|    1|
#|      T2|       2|    2|
#+--------+--------+-----+
```

Note: You need to wrap the column names in backticks since they have spaces in them as explained in this post: [How to express a column which name contains spaces in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053095/how-to-express-a-column-which-name-contains-spaces-in-spark-sql/33053334#33053334)

Comment: great hacking @pault . but I have a query that how `Column B` in repeat is treated as a primitive and not as column in sql expression. In api form it is treated as column, isn't it?

Comment: @Ramesh i had trouble getting this to work using DataFrame functions. I don't know why it works in the query.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-dataframe-function) about this behavior

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this:

    from pyspark.sql.window import Window
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/stack1.csv', header = 'True', inferSchema = 'True')

    w = Window.orderBy("Column A")
    df = df.select(row_number().over(w).alias("Index"), col("*"))

    n_to_array = udf(lambda n : [n] * n ,ArrayType(IntegerType()))
    df2 = df.withColumn('Column B', n_to_array('Column B'))
    df3= df2.withColumn('Column B', explode('Column B'))
    df3.show()
```