# Pyspark Generate rows depending on column value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Below is the data input,

```
|       start       |   format_date     |    diff|
+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
|2019-11-15 20:30:00|2019-11-15 18:30:00|     4  |
```

Expected output:

```
start                     format_date                      Diff                    seq
2019-11-15 20:30:00     2019-11-15 18:30:00                  4                       1
2019-11-15 20:30:00     2019-11-15 18:30:00                  4                       2
2019-11-15 20:30:00     2019-11-15 18:30:00                  4                       3
2019-11-15 20:30:00     2019-11-15 18:30:00                  4                       4
```

how do i generate rows depending up on the value (diff) of a column?

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark Replicate Row based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109018/pyspark-replicate-row-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark < 2.4

You can use explode function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as Types

def rangeArr(diff):
  return range(1,diff+1)
rangeUdf = F.udf(rangeArr, Types.ArrayType(Types.IntegerType()))

df = df.withColumn('seqArr', rangeUdf('diff'))

df = df.withColumn('seq', F.explode('seqArr'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Spark 2.4 or greater solution

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([["2019-11-15 20:30:00","2019-11-15 18:30:00" ,4]], ["start", "format_date", "diff"])

df.select("*", F.explode(F.sequence(F.lit(1), F.col("diff"))).alias("seq")).show()


+-------------------+-------------------+----+---+
|              start|        format_date|diff|seq|
+-------------------+-------------------+----+---+
|2019-11-15 20:30:00|2019-11-15 18:30:00|   4|  1|
|2019-11-15 20:30:00|2019-11-15 18:30:00|   4|  2|
|2019-11-15 20:30:00|2019-11-15 18:30:00|   4|  3|
|2019-11-15 20:30:00|2019-11-15 18:30:00|   4|  4|
```