# is there a way we can rename or alias column with blank space in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am getting error while renaming a column, is there anyway i can rename it, as there are space in column name

`df=df.withColumnRenamed("std deviation","stdDeviation")`

`Error:AnalysisException: Attribute name "std deviation" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.`

I tried another way by using alias, but no success.

`df=df.select(col("std deviation").alias("stdDeviation"))`

is there a way I can rename columns that contain space?

`Error:AnalysisException: Attribute name "std deviation" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.`

Comment: You should use backticks ` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053095/how-to-express-a-column-which-name-contains-spaces-in-spark-sql

Comment: hi @Cronenberg, I am reading a parquet file and i just want to rename the column. Right now, with the logic in the link, i am getting error that df not found. df = spark.read.option("header", "true").parquet(source_file_path)
sqlContext.sql("""SELECT \`Standard deviation\` FROM df""").show error: df table not found

Answer (score 1):

It is weird that you are using

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").parquet(source_file_path)
```

You don't need the header option when reading parquet files.

Besides that, you should use

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed("`old name`", "new_name").
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

```
>>> input_df.show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
+-----+

>>> input_df = input_df.withColumnRenamed("value", "test value")
>>> input_df.show()
+----------+
|test value|
+----------+
|         1|
|         2|
|         3|
+----------+

# The other way round #
>>> input_df = input_df.withColumnRenamed("test value", "value")
>>> input_df.show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
+-----+
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working for parquet files. Have you tried to rename parquet file containing columns with white space?

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.1.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetSchemaConverter.scala#L565), there is no way to do that with Spark. One alternative way to go is using `pandas.read_parquet`, it should work. However, I'm not sure how big your file is and if your local computer (or cluster driver) can handle it.